# Create nested array in custom soap webservice mirth

Tags: java, soap, mirth, mirth-connect

I'm creating a custom webservice to host in Mirth. I wanted to create nested Array inside this SOAP structure. There may be other ways of creating SOAP, but I'm following this way so that other external JARS need not be used. Currently this is the class I'm doing my getter and setter

```
public class ResultSpecification {
    private String AccessionNumber;
    private String AddtionalPatientHistory;
    private long FacilityCode;
    private String[] Code;
    private String[] Description;

    public String getAccessionNumber() {
        return AccessionNumber;
    }
    public void setAccessionNumber(String AccessionNumber) {
        this.AccessionNumber = AccessionNumber;
    }
    public String getAddtionalPatientHistory() {
        return AddtionalPatientHistory;
    }
    public void setAddtionalPatientHistory(String AddtionalPatientHistory) {
        this.AddtionalPatientHistory = AddtionalPatientHistory;
    }
    public long getFacilityCode() {
        return FacilityCode;
    }
    public void setFacilityCode(long FacilityCode) {
        this.FacilityCode = FacilityCode;
    }
    public String[] getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public void setCode(String[] Code) {
        this.Code = Code;
    }
    public String[] getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String[] Description) {
        this.Description = Description;
    }

@Override
    public String toString() {

        String codeInString = Arrays.toString(Code);
        String descriptionInString = Arrays.toString(Description);

        return "{\"reportDetails\": {\"AccessionNumber\":" + "\"" + AccessionNumber + "\""
                + ", \"AddtionalPatientHistory\":" + "\"" + AddtionalPatientHistory.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"") + "\""
                + ", \"FacilityCode\":" + "\"" + FacilityCode + "\"" +"},\"Hl7Message\":[{\"Code\":" + "\"" + codeInString + "\"" + ", \"Description\":" + "\""
                + descriptionInString + "\"}]}";
    }

}
```

I called this as an Array inside the Webreceiver calling class.That will be the class which I will call inside Mirth and I have provide `super.webServiceReceiver.processData(String.valueOf(str));` within that class.
With the current state I'm getting the below SOAP message.

```
<ray:data>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <TestResult>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <accessionNumber></accessionNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <addtionalPatientHistory></addtionalPatientHistory>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <code></code>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <description></description>
         </TestResult>
 </ray:data>
```

But I'm expecting the SOAP structure in the below format where the tags code and  will be enclosed inside an array by other XML tags.I'm not sure how to construct that in my getter setter class. When I use annotations like @XmlElement it is throwing error inside mirth.

```
 <Statuses>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
      <MessageStatus>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <Code />
     <!--Optional:-->
     <Description />
      </MessageStatus>
     </Statuses>
```

Comment: What error do you get when using `@XMLElement` ?

Comment: Do you need code to match the desired XML output or just working code? IOW are you trying to use code to generate a specific output or vice versa?

Comment: Actually when I use @XmlElement it does not throw error inside Mirth. But When I use the WSDL in SOAPUI, it says unsupported WSDL format. I can use XmlAttributes though. its little strange. I was expecting code to match the SOAP that I Posted later where <code> and <description> are inside an array. I could not create that.